# install redmine in shared apache server

Tags: apache-2.2, ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger, redmine

I'm trying to install Redmine in a shared apache server. This means, I cant make the redmine/public folder my document root.

My server is called server1, so I have some html and php pages at:

```
http://server
http://server/app1
http://server/app2 etc..
```

this apps are at /var/www/app1 and /var/www/app2

redmine is in /var/www/redmine

So I would like to keep this apps and also have Redmine at

```
http://server1/redmine
```

Can I do any setting in my apache server so I can do this? or do I need a new apache service just for Redmine?

By The way, Redmine is working just fine if I keep redmine/public as my document root.

```
UPDATE
```

Not the actual solution I was looking for, but finally I created a Virtual Host in port 81. So I can access with the same Apache server using server1:81

I created a new file at /etc/apache2/sites-available and copied the content of the default file. Then modified the port and the document root to /redmine/public

Then I added the new host to apache with the commmand

```
a2ensite NewHostFileName
```

Finally

```
service apache2 reload
```

Comment: Look at [the `Alias` directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html).

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how I can use Alias for this. What configuration file I have to edit and what I have to add?? Right now, with my current configuration, Redmine shows a Ruby (rack error): No such file or directory - config.ru